# 商用と非商用でライセンスを分けることは可能か

Tags: github, ライセンス

非商用の場合はMIT、商用の場合は有料ライセンスにすることは可能でしょうか？

また、Githubで開発を行なっているのですが、LICENCEファイルは作成せずに、
README.mdや公式サイト等にライセンスについて記述すればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

利用者に2つのライセンスのどちらかを選ばせることは一般的に行われていて、**デュアルライセンス**と呼ばれています。ですがMITライセンスは負わせる責務が著作権表示のみですので、商用利用を禁じることはできません。

MITではなくより強いライセンス、例えばソースコードを開示する義務が発生するGPLやAGPLをオープンソース側に採用すれば有償ライセンスを選ぶインセンティブが生まれます。GPLとのデュアルライセンスの例としてはMySQLなどがあります。

Answer (score 5):

@pgrho さんの書かれているように、MITライセンスでは制限無く商用利用は可能です。(なお、GPL/AGPLでもライセンスの範囲で商用利用は許可されています。たとえば、商用Webサービスの内部でMySQLを使うような場合、GPLライセンスで利用できますし、ソースコードに変更を加えても公開義務はありません。)

> 非商用の場合はMIT、商用の場合は有料ライセンス

このようにしたい場合には、MITライセンスを改変して「非商用に限って許可する」という条項を付け加えたライセンスと、商用ライセンスの二者択一にするのが良いでしょう。オープンソースでは無くなりますが、フリーソフトウェアを名乗ることはできます。